# Why is applicationDidFinishLaunching NOT being called in my macOS document based app with a storyboard?

Tags: macos, cocoa, storyboard, appdelegate, macos-sierra

I'm working on a Swift document based app for macOS and I discovered that the appDelegate method `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is never called. The app delegate is being set correctly and I can see in the debugger that the NSApplication object has the delegate set. Why isn't this method being called when the application launches?

Note: my storyboard has an entry point set to a 'welcome window' controller (in case that has anything to do with this problem).

Answer (score 1):

Resolved: my method signature was wrong.  It was:

```
applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification)
```

When it should have been:

```
applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
```

This probably happened wile converting to the current Swift syntax.